# Form not getting submit after getting token from stripe

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am facing an error after getting the token from stripe. form is not submitting after i am getting the token form stripe.

i have tried so far

```
$('#payment-form').submit(function(e){
    if (!$('#payment-form').data('cc-on-file')) 
        {
           e.preventDefault();
          Stripe.setPublishableKey($('.form-horizontal').data('stripe-publishable-key'));

          var Token = Stripe.createToken({
            number: $('.card-number').val(),
            cvc: $('.card-cvc').val(),
            exp_month: $('.card-expiry-month').val(),
            exp_year: $('.card-expiry-year').val()
          }, stripeResponseHandler);

          return false;

        } 
});
```

stripeResponseHandler function

```
function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {
    if (response.error) {
        $('.error')
            .removeClass('hide')
            .find('.alert')
            .text(response.error.message);

            setTimeout(function(){
             $('.error')
            .addClass('hide')
            .find('.alert')
            .text('');
        },1000);

    }
    else 
    {        
        var token = response['id'];
        $('#payment-form').append("<input type='hidden' name='stripeToken' value='" + token + "'/>");
        $('#payment-form').get(0).submit(); // getting error here

    }
}
```

Error i am getting

> $(...).get(...).submit is not a function

Comment: If `payment-form` is the form element id, then `$('#payment-form').submit();` should be enough to submit that form.

Comment: Its not working i have tried

Comment: @dhilt No, becaus it will end to call his event handler which makes a `preventDefault` and it will also make an infinite loop.

Comment: I have tried without  preventDefault but still not working

Comment: Actually the problem is solved i have given id to submit btn <button id = "submit" > when i removed the submit id from btn then it works fine.

Comment: but i don't have idea how it works. whats the issue with submit id